# ASP.net MVC and Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an ASP.net MVC(3) app that is an intrAnet-style app - access by Domain users only.  I have not decorated any of my controller actions with [Authorize] attributes, I just enabled Windows authentication at the IIS level - perhaps not the best idea - because now I'd like an action or two (or even an entire controller) to be open if possible.

I'm thinking I need to go back and decorate all my actions, not rely on the IIS setting, and 'undecorate'  the ones I wish to be open, but thought I'd ask if there might be an alternative suggestion first.

Comment: You could create different areas and control access to them via web.config, but honestly, decoration of controllers will always be your best solution here IMHO.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll have a look and see if that makes sense - appreciate it.